# Redis Nodejs (Express) switch to database if servers go offline

Tags: node.js, express, redis

I would like to know how I can do some sort of error handling in Redis NodeJS. I want the code to check if Redis server is online, and if it isnt it switches to fetch from the Database instead. I am using Redis 4.0, the issue I am getting is if I use the current async function, and the server is down it just hangs there

Comment: Which client are you using (`redis | ioredis`)?

Comment: I am using Redis

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`disableOfflineQueue`](https://github.com/redis/node-redis/blob/master/docs/client-configuration.md#createclient-configuration)

https://github.com/redis/node-redis/blob/master/docs/FAQ.md#what-happens-when-the-network-goes-down
"If don't want to queue commands in memory until a new socket is established, set the disableOfflineQueue option to true in the client configuration. This will result in those commands being rejected."